# Ubuntu believes wireless connection is of ethernet type (16.04, Atheros adapter)

Tags: drivers, wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an MSI G40 with Qualcomm Atheros wireless card (dual boot Windows 10). It worked fine until I tried to connect to Ethernet, at which point what was my wireless connection became "wired", and unusable. It seems that Linux now believes that both my connections are wired ethernet connections (see ifconfig below). I tried reinstalling the proprietary drivers (/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174) and the linux firmware, but no luck. Upon turning my computer on and off enough times, I obtained wireless again briefly, but it then stopped working again. I made sure to ifconfig /release all my addresses in Windows and turn off fast boot

ifconfig returns:

```
enp60s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:f1:15:a5  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:89744 (89.7 KB)  TX bytes:89744 (89.7 KB)

wlp61s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:10:41:bc:c7:0d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And nmcli dev:

```
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION    
enp60s0  ethernet  connected     Auto Ethernet 
wlp61s0  ethernet  disconnected  --            
lo       loopback  unmanaged     --
```

wlp61s0  should not be ethernet but wireless. How can I change this?

My setup is below:

```
3c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:1155]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
3d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Killer N1525 Wireless-AC [1a56:1525]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
       logical name: enp60s0
       version: 10
       serial: d8:cb:8a:f1:15:a5
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:28 memory:dd400000-dd43ffff ioport:c000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3d:00.0
       logical name: wlp61s0
       version: 20
       serial: b0:10:41:bc:c7:0d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-28-generic firmware=SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:26 memory:dd200000-dd3fffff
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Have you updated ubuntu lately?

Comment: yes.  I did an apt-get update after installing